# Command line for Eclipse Java formatter

Tags: eclipse, command-line, formatter

I just wonder if there is a command line tool for eclipse java file formatter.
Or if there is an ant task to execute it.

In my scenario, there are 2 java formatters, one is for android formatter, the other is our internal formatter.

So we have to change it between these two formatter.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for but if im guessing correctly it is something like this: [formatting-your-code-using-the-eclipse-code-formatter](https://peterfriese.wordpress.com/2007/05/28/formatting-your-code-using-the-eclipse-code-formatter/).

This describes how to execute the eclipse built in formatter using the command line. You can also enable the format per project.

Comment: link is dead :(

Comment: it's seems was moved to:
https://peterfriese.wordpress.com/2007/05/28/formatting-your-code-using-the-eclipse-code-formatter/

Comment: @EnriqueS.Filiage This one's dead too.